# How to get single key from array of array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a structure like

```
  const test = [
    {
      items: [
        {
          id: "tete",
        },
        {
          id: "tete",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      items: [
        {
          id: "tete",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

How go i get all the 'id' value from these array using javascript.

Comment: You could use a combination of `reduce` and `map`, such as: `const ids = test.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b.items.map(c => c.id)], [])`. you can look at the documentation for these functions on the MDN [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

The new [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) can do it all in one line with the regular [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const test = [{items:[{id:"tete",},{id:"tete",},],},{items:[{id:"tete"}]}];

const result = test.flatMap((e) => e.items.map((i) => i.id));

console.log(result);
```

It is equivalent to the following:

```
const result = test.map((e) => e.items.map((i) => i.id)).flat();
```

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates, you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) after you got all the ids.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option to extract the `id` values:

```js
const test = [
    {
        items: [
            {
                id: "tete",
            },
            {
                id: "tete",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        items: [
            {
                id: "tete",
            },
        ],
    },
];

const ids = test.reduce((acc, element) => {
    for (const item of element.items) {
        acc.push(item.id);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(ids);
```

Comment: one-liner for the callback: `acc.concat(element.items.map(({ id }) => id)))`